# java Exception Propagation

Tags: java

check out the program

```
public class ExceptionPropagation {
  void method3() {
    throw new Exception(); //raises exception
    // throw new ArithmeticException(); NO Exception arised
  }
  void method1() {
    try{
      method3();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception is handled here");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ExceptionPropagation obj=new ExceptionPropagation();
    obj.method1();
  }
}
```

Why it worked in the case of unchecked exceptions, why not with checked?
can anyone explain it related to jvm side also?

Comment: This is the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions. If some code could throw a checked exception it must be taken care of by either declaring a throws clause for it or by catching it. Unchecked exceptions do not require this. See [The Java Tutorials - Lessons: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of exception.

  1. Checked Exception
  2. Unchecked Exception

Checked exceptions are compile time exceptions. i.e it will be checked at compile time. In your case `Exception` class is a checked exception. So you have to explicitly mention the keyword `throws` in your method signature to pass the compilation error.

Unchecked exceptions are runtime exceptions. i.e it will be checked only at runtime. `ArithmethicException` is an unchecked exception.